# Git svn - no changes, no branches (except master), rebase/info is not working

Tags: git, svn, version-control, migration

I know that similar questions were asked before, but I think my is a little bit different, so please don't point me to existing threads.

I'm migrating our old svn repo to git.

I did

`git svn clone path --authors-file abc.txt --no-metadata`

and everything seemend legit to me. Then I did

`git remote add origin xyz`

and

`git push --all origin`

and it also worked.

I created this repo as test one, with only me having access to both local repo and `origin`. No changes were made in project held on this repo, nothing to commit, no pushing and so on. There is also only one branch, because someone initialized svn years ago without creating proper folder structure (branches, trunk, tags).
Meanwhile someone pushed their work to `svn`, so I tried to `git svn fetch` (which worked), and `git svn rebase` which didn't, giving me error:

`Unable to determine upstream SVN information from working tree history`

Is there any reason why `git svn` decided to stop working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that reimporting repository from `svn` without `--no-metadata` did the trick.